# How to get the ListBox' tapped item to print it somewhere else?

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, uwp

I show file's lines in my `ListBox`. I need to grab the line that is tapped by user and show it as the `Button`'s `Content`.

I did something like this:

```
void OnItemTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    firstElement.Content = itemsControl.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

In xaml I have:

```
<Button Name="firstElement"                
        Content="{Binding}"
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
        Tapped="OnItemTapped" />
```

This way `OnItemTapped` sends data to my Button.

The data is pulled from:

```
<ListBox x:Name="itemsControl"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         FontSize="24"
         Width="1100"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center">
```

The problem is that instead of data shown correctly within `ListBox` I get `MyNamespace.ItemsData` which is class's address, where I keep strings from splitted `ListBox` line( I show each line in 5 `TextBlocks` - one for each word).

```
public class ItemsData
{
    public string value0 { get; set; }
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
    public string value3 { get; set; }
    public string value4 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast to your Model first then select what property you need to show. Like this:

```
firstElement.Content = (itemsControl.SelectedItem as ItemsData).value0;
```

Based on your design to get all properties you can do like this:

```
var x = (itemsControl.SelectedItem as ItemsData);
firstElement.Content = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}" , x.value0 , x.value1 , x.value2 , x.value3 , x.value4);
```

And in C#6 you could:

```
firstElement.Content = string.Format($"{x.value0},{x.value1},{x.value2},{x.value3},{x.value4}");
```

Comment: wouldn't that always get the first item's text regardless of which one is tapped?

Comment: @AlexDrenea...The OP needs to cast to model first to access the models properties otherwise it returns `MyNamespace.ItemsData`.

Comment: sure, but the code you provided will always set the content to the value0 which is clearly not what he wants.

Comment: @AlexDrenea...`value0` is just an example of accessing model's properties after casting.

Comment: Correct, but it does not solve the OPs question to actually show the content of the item that he's tapped. So your answer is incorrect, or incomplete at best.

Comment: It gives me always just one value.

Comment: @paddy...Do you need to get all properties?

Comment: well I was looking for a way to get all words from the line(5 textblocks) and show them as Button's content.

Comment: so @paddy the ItemsData class represents One item of your list?

Comment: @paddy...Based on your current design I think you need to concatenate all properties.

Comment: I used ItemsData when I was needing to split each line into separate words, to put each word on separate textblock in separate column of design

Comment: All ItemsData represents a whole line. And a whole line is what I need to use for buttons content

Comment: @paddy...Based on your current design and to get all properties the only way I think should be this: `var x = (itemsControl.SelectedItem as ItemsData);
            firstElement.Content = (x.value0 + x.value1 + x.value2 + x.value3 + x.value4);`

Comment: noo, don't do "+" with strings. That's just bad. Use string.Format, string.Concat or the new inline string concatenation in C#6 $"{x.value0} {x.value1} {x.value2} {x.value3} {x.value4}".

Comment: For saving the pulled data I use the same solution, right? Say, aside of the button content, I would like to keep the data for later, when my page is out of focus for example, or when I need to pull this data from main to other page?

Comment: if you need that data in other places, better to "store" it directly in your class. Check my answer for that kind of approach.

Comment: Is it possible to exchange this kind of data between pages? Lets say that same text should be pulled by button on page other than MainPage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ElementName binding:

```
<Button Name="firstElement"                
        Content="{Binding ElementName=itemsControl, Path=SelectedItem}"
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

But because SelectedItem is a ItemsClass instance you need to override its ToString() method to get the text you need:

```
public class ItemsData
{
    public string value0 { get; set; }
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
    public string value3 { get; set; }
    public string value4 { get; set; }

    public string AllValues 
    {
        get 
        {
            return $"{value0} {value1} {value2} {value3} {value4}";
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return AllValues;
    }
}
```

Check [this](http://expediteapps.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/UWPBinding.pdf) great document for an extensive list of binding properties.

*Note: Your list will handle all the selection display and highlights so at least for that, you don't need to use the Tapped event.

Comment: I used tapping to give user option to select and highlight choice.